# Is there any issue for my packaged box file when using Vagrant?

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox

When I use Vagrant to setup VM,I downloaded a box called "centos_scalefactory",it booted well.

```
E:\vagrantZZZ>vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'centos_scalefactory'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: vagrantZZZ_default_1464241176788_30693
==> default: Fixed port collision for 22 => 2222. Now on port 2200.
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
default: 22 (guest) => 2200 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2200
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default:
    default: Vagrant insecure key detected. Vagrant will automatically replace
    default: this with a newly generated keypair for better security.
    default:
    default: Inserting generated public key within guest...
    default: Removing insecure key from the guest if it's present...
    default: Key inserted! Disconnecting and reconnecting using new SSH key...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => E:/vagrantZZZ
```

However,I use the box that I packaged by myself,I stopped when I vagrant up it.

```
E:\vagrantMIN>vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
==> default: Waiting for cleanup before exiting...
stopped........................
```

I really don't know why,there is no any additional configuration in Vagrantfile(just default)
Is there any problem existing when I install myself VM?

Thanks...........

Comment: can you detail how you package your box yourself (packer, repackage ...) and run `vagrant up --debug` and post the log to pastebin or gist and point it to the question, it might reveal important info

Comment: @Frédéric Henri I just try vagrant up --debug,but it seems hobbrified the log info repeated printed on screen.There a mass info that I really don't know which part to cut

Comment: yep log can be long, just put it on pastebin or gist - dont cut anything - meanwhile explain how you package your box

Comment: I almost find the cause.Just because I select minimal Version in the process of Wizard of install.